# Makefile with different compiler flags for source files

Tags: c++, gcc, makefile, g++

How do I use different compiler flags for different source files in a Makefile?  For example, I'd like a Makefile that will produce:

```
g++ -c -COMPILER_FLAGS_1   -g source1.cpp -o source1.o

g++ -c -COMPILER_FLAGS_2   -g source2.cpp -o source2.o
g++ -c -COMPILER_FLAGS_2   -g source3.cpp -o source3.o
g++ -c -COMPILER_FLAGS_2   -g source4.cpp -o source4.o

g++ -c -COMPILER_FLAGS_3   -g source5.cpp -o source5.o
g++ -c -COMPILER_FLAGS_3   -g source6.cpp -o source6.o
g++ -c -COMPILER_FLAGS_3   -g source7.cpp -o source7.o

g++ -g -o output source1.o source2.o source3.o source4.o source5.o source6.o source7.o
```

At the moment I've got about 20 source files (and that's expected to grow), so an easy to maintain file would be nice.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could do something like the following (untested, so the syntax might be slightly off):

```
OBJS_1 := source1.o
OBJS_2 := source2.o source3.o source4.o
OBJS_3 := source5.o source6.o source7.o

OBJS := $(OBJS_1) $(OBJS_2) $(OBJS_3)

output: $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) -g -o $@ $^

$(OBJS_1): CXXFLAGS := $(COMPILER_FLAGS_1)
$(OBJS_2): CXXFLAGS := $(COMPILER_FLAGS_2)
$(OBJS_3): CXXFLAGS := $(COMPILER_FLAGS_3)

$(OBJS): %.o: %.cpp
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) -g $< -o $@
```

Comment: @Oli_Charlesworth  Somebodies given me a c file, and I need to use functions from it.  What do you think would be the best way of adding it to the makefile?

Comment: @user1208914: I don't understand the problem.  Why can't you treat it like any other source file?

Comment: @Oli_Charlesworth because of the line $(OBJS): %.o: %.cpp It changes all .o files into .cpp, whereas the c file is  a .c

Comment: @user1208914: Ah, I see.  You can add a second rule, `$(OBJS): %.o: %.c $(CC) ...`.  Make will choose the appropriate one automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Here is UNIX/LINUX makefile which I wrote and tested on Solaris LINUX to handle different compilation flags for different sections of a GNUmakefile. Please let me know if it can be improved. Thank you

```
# GNUmakefile
#
# makefile for mdRightFielder
#
# Builds:
#   libmdRightFielder.so or libmdRightFielder.sl

ifndef SUB
include ../header.mk

else

VPATH=../Source:../Source/PCRE:../Source/SQLite:../../cpswindows/Source:../../util/mdLicense
INCL=-I../Include -I../Include/PCRE -I../Include/SQLite -I../../cpswindows/Include -I ../../util -I../../util/mdLicense
APIOBJ=cGlobalDataDestructor.o cPCRE.o CppInterface.o cRightFielder-FillTokenGaps.o
PCREOBJ=pcre_chartables.o pcre_compile.o pcre_exec.o pcre_fullinfo.o pcre_get.o pcre_globals.o pcre_newline.o \
    pcre_tables.o pcre_try_flipped.o
SQLITEOBJ=sqlite3.o
CPSWINDOWSOBJ=BinarySearch.o cConfigFile.o cCriticalSection.o cDateTime.o cException.o cFile.o cSQLite.o \
    QuickSort.o StringFunctions.o
MDLICENSEOBJ=CBigNum.o mdLicense.o RSA.o

ifeq ($(CPU),sparc)
    ifdef workshop
        CALIGN=-xmemalign=1s 
        ifdef release
            CXXALIGN=-Qoption cg -xmemalign=1s
        else
            CXXALIGN=-Qoption ccfe -y-xmemalign=1s
        endif
    endif
endif

COMPILER_FLAGS_1=-D_NO_GUI 
COMPILER_FLAGS_2=-D_NO_GUI -DHAVE_CONFIG_H 


CXXFLAGS+=-DPCRE_STATIC -DUSE_STATIC
CFLAGS+=-D_NO_GUI -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DPCRE_STATIC -DUSE_STATIC
DEPFLAGS+=-DLINK_SIZE=2 -D_NO_GUI -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DPCRE_STATIC -DUSE_STATIC

.PHONY: all clean

all:    libmdRightFielder.so
    cp -fp ../Include/mdRightFielder.h ../../util/mdEnums.h libmdRightFielder.so $(SHIP)
    if [ `uname` = HP-UX ] ; \
    then \
      /bin/mv -f $(SHIP)/libmdRightFielder.so $(SHIP)/libmdRightFielder.sl ; \
    fi

clean:
    rm -f *.o *.so *.sl deps
    rm -f core core.[0-9]*

$(APIOBJ): CXXFLAGS+=$(COMPILER_FLAGS_1) 
$(PCREOBJ): CXXFLAGS+=$(COMPILER_FLAGS_2) 

MARYOBJS = $(APIOBJ) $(PCREOBJ)



libmdRightFielder.so: \
    $(MARYOBJS)
     -$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCL) $(SHARED) $^ -o $@ $(LDLIBS)

mary:
    %.o : %.cpp  # cancel implicit CPP compilation rule

        %.o :  %.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCL) $(PIC) $< -o $@ -c


        %.o : %.c     # cancel implicit C compilation rule

        %.o : %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCL) $(PIC) $< -o $@ -c

endif
```

Comment: header.mk is a proprietary UNIX product of our company for Cross UNIX platform development. It defines CXX, CC, CXXFLAGS, CFLAGS depending on the output shell uname for each separate UNIX machine. I can provide an excerpt of this file at frank_chang91@hotmail.com. THank you.